# NGINX location directive in stream

Tags: nginx

I've installed Nginx on one of my servers in order to be used as a load balancer for my [Rancher](https://rancher.com/) application.
I based my configuration on the one found here: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/ha/create-nodes-lb/nginx/

And so my config is:

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

worker_processes 4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

events {
    worker_connections 8192;
}

stream {
    upstream rancher_servers_http {
        least_conn;
        server <ipnode1>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <ipnode2>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <ipnode3>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
    }
    server {
        listen     80;

        proxy_pass rancher_servers_http;
    }

    upstream rancher_servers_https {
        least_conn;
        server <ipnode1>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <ipnode2>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <ipnode3>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
    }
    server {
        listen     443;
        proxy_pass rancher_servers_https;
    }
}
```

My configuration is working as expected but I've recently installed [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) on my cluster. Which is giving me the following error:

> - Your web server is not properly set up to resolve “/.well-known/caldav”. Further information can be found in the
>     documentation.
> - Your web server is not properly set up to resolve “/.well-known/carddav”. Further information can be found in the
>     documentation.

So I would like to add a "location" directive but I'm not able to do it.
I tried to update my config as follow:

```
...

stream {
    upstream rancher_servers_http {
        ...
    }
    server {
        listen     80;
        proxy_pass rancher_servers_http;

        location /.well-known/carddav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
        }
        location /.well-known/caldav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
        }
    }

    upstream rancher_servers_https {
        ...
    }
    server {
        listen     443;
        proxy_pass rancher_servers_https;

        location /.well-known/carddav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
        }
        location /.well-known/caldav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
        }
    }
}
```

But it's telling me

> "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:21

Assuming location directive is not allowed in a stream configuration I tried to add an http block like this:

```
...

stream {
    ...
}

http {
  server {
      listen 443;

      location /.well-known/carddav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
      }
      location /.well-known/caldav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
      }
   }
  server {
      listen 80;

      location /.well-known/carddav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
      }
      location /.well-known/caldav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
      }
   }
}
```

But then I got this message:

> bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)

(same for the port 80).

Can someone help me with this ? How can I add the location directive without affecting my actual configuration ?

Thank you for reading.

## Edit

Well it seems that the `stream` directive prevent me from adding other standard directives. I tried to add the `client_max_body_size` inside `server` but I'm having the same issue:

> directive is not allowed here

Answer (score 7):

Right now your setup uses nginx as an TCP proxy. Such configuration of nginx passes through traffic without analysis - it can be ssh, rdp, whatever traffic and it will work regardless of protocols because nginx do not try to check stream content.

That is the reason why location directive does not work in context of streams - it is http protocol related function.

To take advantage of high level protocol analysis nginx need to be aware of protocol going through it, i.e. be configured as an HTTP reverse proxy.

For it to work server directive should be placed in http scope instead of stream scope.

```
http {
  server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name XXXX;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://rancher_servers_http;
    }
    location /.well-known/carddav {
      proxy_pass http://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
    }
    location /.well-known/caldav {
      proxy_pass http://$host:$server_port/remote.php/dav;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name xxxx;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://rancher_servers_http;
    }
  }
}
```

Drawback of this approach for you would be need of certificate management reconfiguration.
But you will load off ssl encryption to nginx and gain intelligent ballancing based on http queries.